# WPF Canvas Create object

Tags: c#, wpf, object, canvas

I am using WPF and C# and I have a canvas with rectangles on it (like a maze). Now i want to create a character who moves (with the help of an algorithm) through this maze. Therefore I created a new class called character, but my problem starts here: How do I create an object on the canvas which has an image, a position and which can access the methods and attributes from the character-class?
So the final thing should look like this:

```
private class MainWindow
{

   //Here the canvas is made visible and the rectangles are being drawn on the canvas

   //Then a method should start to create the character and move him through the maze

   //it should look like (character.move(1) so the character moves one step forward etc.)

}

private class Character
{
//here are the methods and attributes the character should have
}
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the problem from the opposite direction, it's much easier to solve.

Create your character object, hook it up so that everything works as you expect in your data (model).  Then, you'll want to add properties that represent the location of the character, such as

```
public int XCoordinate { get; set; }
public int YCoordinate { get; set; }
```

Make sure the movement is done *model-side*.  If you try to drive movement based on the visual display, it will over complicate the program.

Next, define the view of the character in your canvas, something like this:

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Image Canvas.Left="{Binding XCoordinate}" Canvas.Top="{Binding YCoordinate}" .../>
</Canvas>
```

Last, make sure your binding syntax is correct (did you set the DataContext?) and be sure to set up NotifyPropertyChanged to taste (both of these are well-covered elsewhere).  Then you will be set up with a neatly divided model and view, and it should be much easier to focus on movement logic or whatever else you should desire.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to define the properties and the methods for the `Character` class. This would include (as you have indicated in the question) a `Move(Position newPosition)` method. `Position` can be a wrapper over the [`Point`structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx). The `Character` class also needs to contain a reference to the Canvas in which the character is present. This is required since when you call 'character.Move(position)`, the character can be moved in the canvas that the character is current associated with.

Furthermore, the `MainWindow` can contain a reference to the character or a collection of characters (in case your requirement if for multiple characters). The actual creation can be during the initialization of the `MainWindow` or can be [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization). Post initialization, your algorithm can work on the character instance.

Comment: Ok, I created the Character Class with the methods but I have another problem: How can I access the canvas thorugh this character class? The Canvas is only known in the MainWindow class and I can't find where I can change this so that it is also known in the character class.

Comment: I tried to add :MainWindow after the public class character and now I can access the same objects the MainWindow can access, but I can't seem to change them :/

Comment: @dingoglotz, which property are you trying to change?

Comment: I tried this: Canvas.SetLeft(CharImage, iXCoordinate) but it does not work with CharImage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden either.

Comment: @dingoglotz, which of the 2 statements is not working (`Canvas.SetLeft()` or `charImage.Visibility` assignment)?

Comment: Both of them are not working. Or rather, they reset themself. I have a MainWindow class and a character class. In the MainWindow class I make an instance of the character class and call a method. In the method are the methods Canvas.SetLeft and charImage.Visibility. And that is working fine. But when the program comes to the point where all the methods from the instance are finished, so when it is going back to the methods in the MainWindow-Class, the propertys are all reset. I don't know why :/

Comment: @dingoglotz, are you passing the current window/canvas as the argument while creating the `charImage` instance? You can verify whether the properties are being changed after the call by giving a [breakpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) after the statement.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right.. In the Canvas (canv) I have declared an Image called charImage. Then in the MainWindow class I can change the propertys of this image through methods like "charImage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden", but now I want to change these propertys through an instance of another class (class char). But because the class char does not know the canvas I added :MainWindow behind the class (I assume this is to make it a child of the MainWindow class) and now I can write "charImage.Visibility..." in the methods in the char class. So then, I create an instance of the

Comment: char class in the MainWindow class. This instance then calls the method of it's own class to change the visibility and when I set a breakpoint there I can see that this property is really changed. But then, when the programm comes to the point where it is back in the MainWindow class, the property-changes made from the instance are reseted. Hope I explained it good enough

Comment: @dingoglotz, I would suggest that you try out the solution posted by @ianschol. It involves creating properties in the `Character` class that expose the (x,y) coordinates of its image. These properties are then *bound* to the corresponding properties of `charImage` in the Canvas.

Comment: Ok I tried this binding-thing a bit and looked up tutorials, but seems like I am too dumb to do it properly :/ I have done the exact thing ianschol posted, but I am stuck at the part with the DataContext and Update-thing. How do I properly set a DataContext with this and how can I update the values? All I've done up until now is to set the canvas.Left and canvas.Top to {Binding iXCoordinate} and {Binding iYCoordinate} and iXCoordinate and iYCoordinate are propertys in the character-class with get and set function :/